# Внедрить поддомены в Express проект

Tags: node.js, express

Я для себя пишу скелет Express приложения, дабы его использовать в дальнейшем.
На данный момент я хочу понять, как мне внедрить в него поддомен subdomain. Хочу использовать для этого [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost), но не понимаю как это реализовать в коде.

Репозиторий: https://bitbucket.org/Oliver_Patterson/salary-info/src/master/

Comment: во-первых есть [полный интернет "правильных решений"](https://www.google.com/search?q=express+subdomain); во-вторых формат so подразумевает поиск объективного ответа на вопрос, а не "хочу услышать варианты" и по непонятным критериям чё-нибудь выберу

Comment: Тогда на какой форум я могу обращаться с необъективными вопросами?

Comment: @nörbörnën, я обновил вопрос.